# How to I copy system info to clip board?

Tags: gnome

I have navigated to Settings > About to view system info. Now I want to copy to clipboard. How? There is no button, and I cannot select?

Answer (score 1):

<sup>**Note:** As there is no version mentioned, this answer will involve the OS that is currently installed on my personal notebook. I make no guarantees that what works on my machine will work on yours (or anyone else's).</sup>

The About panel in Settings is not specifically designed to allow a person to copy everything at once as there are few instances where this level of detail is necessary. This would also bring about the question of how to format such a list, as people will want different things based on personal preferences and, as the last few years of Gnome development has shown, the Gnome development team isn't particularly interested in anyone else's opinion.

That said, you should be able to copy individual items from the About panel by doing one of the two following actions:

1. Select *only* the right-side text of an item, right-click, and choose "Copy"
2. Click within the text of a right-side item, select the entire value with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>, then copy with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>

[image: Settings - About]

If you are looking for a way to quickly copy all data to the clipboard, you may be interested in a Terminal tool called `screenfetch`. This can be installed with a simple:

```
sudo apt install screenfetch
```

From there you can run the command, which will give you something like this:

``````
jason@carbon:~$ screenfetch
                          ./+o+-       jason@carbon
                  yyyyy- -yyyyyy+      OS: Ubuntu 22.04 jammy
               ://+//////-yyyyyyo      Kernel: x86_64 Linux 5.15.0-18-generic
           .++ .:/++++++/-.+sss/`      Uptime: 7d 16h 36m
         .:++o:  /++++++++/:--:/-      Packages: 1904
        o:+o+:++.`..```.-/oo+++++/     Shell: bash 5.1.16
       .:+o:+o/.          `+sssoo+/    Resolution: 1920x1080
  .++/+:+oo+o:`             /sssooo.   DE: GNOME 41.4
 /+++//+:`oo+o               /::--:.   WM: Mutter
 \+/+o+++`o++o               ++////.   WM Theme: Adwaita
  .++.o+++oo+:`             /dddhhh.   GTK Theme: Yaru [GTK2/3]
       .+.o+oo:.          `oddhhhh+    Icon Theme: Yaru
        \+.++o+o``-````.:ohdhhhhh+     Font: Ubuntu 11
         `:o+++ `ohhhhhhhhyo++os:      Disk: 3.3T / 16T (22%)
           .o:`.syhhhhhhh/.oo++o`      CPU: Intel Core i5-7200U @ 4x 3.1GHz [38.0°C]
               /osyyyyyyo++ooo+++/     GPU: Intel Corporation HD Graphics 620 (rev 02)
                   ````` +oo+++o\:     RAM: 3040MiB / 7847MiB
                          `oo++.
``````

Comment: Is there seriously no way to print the About section of Ubuntu with a native terminal command?